# Received accepted answer, then it disappeared

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

On this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496863/ajax-submit-form-without-refreshing-the-page/26496945#26496945) I worked with the OP over several days to get his code working. He accepted the answer about an hour ago, and suddenly that acceptance is gone. Did the system 'burp' or was the acceptance removed?

In addition we had spent a lot of time going back and forth in comments - a lot of which appears to be lost now. I cannot do chat from my current location, so sometimes end up in lengthy comment exchanges.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26496863/timeline - looks like the OP hesitated _a lot_...

Comment: The acceptance was removed. It switched about 3 times in about a minute; which is pretty weird.

Comment: Janaka is not the OP on that, and is attributed to those switches.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The name is the name of the author of the answer that was accepted or unaccepted, not the name of the person who accepted/unaccepted.

Comment: Gotcha. Took me a moment to get the format of it all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OP removed the acceptance.  It happens.  He can accept or unaccept whatever he wants to.